# Marketing Cloud - User email sending authentication - from address

Tags: marketing-cloud

I was recently told that I was no longer able to send emails from validated user email address in Marketing Cloud. Previously we have validated the emails and then checked the box to add them to the reply from box in Salesforce when sending an email.

I just tried to do this and I was not only able to but also didn't get any error messages.

Can anyone confirm if this feature is being removed and should not be used or if I have been passed on some incorrect information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also got the same email recently. For my case, I have just contacted support and they said to ignore that mail and it is working fine.

I believe in your email they would have mentioned the affected domain name & MID, just check if the domain is still delegated to exact target name servers.

You can just check if the domain is delegated or not with this link - https://xnnd.com/dele.cgi?t=dele&d=example.com

Just enter you domain and you can see if it's delegated or not.

If its delegated then you are good. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I contacted support who confirmed that this is still possible and that the original communication was misleading. They mentioned this may change in the future.